# net localgroup administrators is crashing my code

Tags: c++, windows, security, c++11

The first part of my code runs like I want, but when I go to make the account admin using net localgroup administrators the code crashes and i get a message saying "Read our privacy statement online..." so i'm assuming my code is setting off some red flags in my pc. I just want this code to run right and I'm not sure how to fix an issue like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
  std::string name;
  std::string admin;
  std::string pass;  
  std::string full;
  std::string mkusr;
  std::string mkadm;
  std::string wait;
  std::string passreq;
  std::string times;
  std::string passchg;
  std::string comment;
  std::string expires;

  std::cout << "What is the new username?\n";
  getline (std::cin, name);
  std::cout << "What is the full name? FIRSTNAME MIDDLEINITIAL LASTNAME\n";
  getline (std::cin, full);
  std::cout << "What password should "<< name <<" have?\n";
  getline (std::cin, pass);
  std::cout << "Is " << name << " an admin?\nY or N\n";
  getline (std::cin, admin);
  std::cout << "Does " << name << " need to have a password\nY or N\n";
  getline (std::cin, passreq);
  std::cout << "When is "<< name <<" authorised to be on? For 24/7 access please enter all\n\nFormat <M,T,W,Th,F,Sa,Su OR M-Su>,<1AM-12PM OR 01:00-23:00>\nTo input multiple time across different days use the ; symbol \nEXAMPLE: M,4AM-5PM;T,1PM-3PM;W-F,8:00-17:00\n";
  getline (std::cin, times);
  std::cout << "Is " << name << " allowed to change his/her password\nY or N\n";
  getline (std::cin, passchg);
  std::cout << "Please give a description for " << name << "\n";
  getline (std::cin, comment);
   std::cout << "When will " << name << "s account expire? If it will never expire please type never\nFormat <MM/DD/YYYY> OR <DD/MM/YYYY> OR <mmm,dd EX:jan,9>\n";
  getline (std::cin, expires);

     system ("cls");
     mkusr = "net user ";
     mkusr += name;
     mkusr += " ";
     mkusr += pass;
     mkusr += " /add ";
     if (passreq == "Y"){
     mkusr += " /passwordreq:yes";
     }
     else {
         mkusr += " /passwordreq:no";
     };
     mkusr += (" /times:");
     times = '"' + times +'"';
     mkusr += times;
     mkusr += " /fullname:";
     full = '"' + full +'"';
     mkusr += full;
     if (passchg == "Y"){
     mkusr += " /passwordchg:yes";
     }
     else{
         mkusr += " /passwordchg:no";
     };
     mkusr += " /comment:";
     comment = '"' + comment +'"';
     mkusr += comment;
     mkusr += " /expires:";
     expires = '"' + expires +'"';
     mkusr += expires;
     //net user 'name' 'pass' /add /passwordreq:'yes/no' /times:'times' /fullname:"'full name'" /passwordchg:'yes/no' /expires:'mm/dd/yyyy||dd/mm/yyy||never' /comment:'cmt'

     //times format   M,4AM-5PM;T,1PM-3PM;M-F,08:00-17:00   all


     std::cout << mkusr;

     const char* mkuser = mkusr.c_str();
     system(mkusr.c_str());
     //system("net user /add << name << pass << /FULLNAME:<<full<<");







  // THIS IS THE PROBLEM AREA

  if (admin == "Y"){
     std::cout << "Ok, I will make " << name << " an admin\n Please press any key to make "<< name <<"an admin.";

     getline (std::cin, wait);

     mkadm = "net localgroup administrators ";
     mkadm += name;
     mkadm += " /add";

     std::cout << "\n " << mkadm;

     const char* mkadm = mkadm;
     system(mkadm);
     //system("net localgroup administrators  << name <<  /add");
// THIS IS THE PROBLEM AREA






  }
  getline (std::cin, wait);
  return 0;

}
```

when I make a code that has only the problem section I get the same crash `

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
  std::string name;
  std::string admin;
  std::string wait;
  std::string mkadm;

  getline (std::cin, admin);
if (admin == "Y"){
     std::cout << "Ok, I will make " << name << " an admin\n Please press any key to make "<< name <<"an admin.";

     getline (std::cin, wait);

     mkadm = "net localgroup administrators ";
     mkadm += name;
     mkadm += " /add";

     std::cout << "\n " << mkadm;

     const char* mkadm = mkadm;
     system(mkadm);
       }
  getline (std::cin, wait);
  return 0;

}`
```

But when I only do

```
system(net localgroup administrators Test /add)
```

It works fine. It just doesnt like when I use a varible in there and/or when I use "const char*"
Sorry for the horrible formatting

Comment: Minimal example, please. Can you reproduce the crash with a single `system("net localgroup ...` line?

Comment: I added it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
const char* mkadm = mkadm;
```

That doesn't do what you were hoping.  The `mkadm` on the right-hand side is the variable you've just defined, not the `std::string` from the outer block.  In other words, you're initializing the variable to be equal to itself, and winding up with a random pointer to somewhere in memory.

Give the two variables different names and your problem will go away:

```
const char * mkadm2 = mkadm.c_str();
system(mkadm2);
```